# Raspberry pi (running Debian) Access Point - Another Pi Crashes It

Tags: dnsmasq, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

I have a Pi3b+ hooked up to my router running hostapd, dnsmasq and openvpn running an airvpn config, it is solid as a rock. It has a static IP on wlan0 192.168.4.1 and serves a local IP range, everything I connect to it works perfectly, with either static IPs or served ones, the firestick streams TV and hardly ever buffers. A success.

However, and a big however  I want another Pi in the network hosting a NAS. I can connect one headless, it gets an IP address and I can `ssh` into it fine. It shows similar speeds to the AP with speedtest-cli.

But as soon as it starts downloading anything, via `wget` or updates etc, it bugs out the network. It occasionally drops `ssh` and can kill reconnects without power offs. Just having it in the network can make the TV buffer. I was initially trying with a Pi4 and put it down to that possibly being dodgy, but it is exactly the same on a brand new Pi3. I've tried 2 SD cards, multiple reflashes, brand new updated busters and old stretch versions, everything I can think of. I've spoken to AirVPN and nothing is throttled their end.

I'm now at a loss, maybe it is something on the AP with hostapd or dnsmasq configs? I don't know? It is ironic that I can connect multiple different OSs to a Pi-AP without issue but can't get another Pi to work with it ‍♂️

I would be extremely grateful if anyone has any ideas, I've solved loads of stuff but am now sadly beaten.

Comment: Anything the NAS is syncing to with a heavy load? How is the storage of the NAS attached to the pi?

Comment: I've removed all the NAS stuff after realising the problem. The issue is happening on brand new clean installs of raspian, old and new versions, different Pi's and cards.

Comment: Wget downloads at kbps speed, sometimes it will get something sometimes it won't, sometimes it kills ssh and the pi itself, requiring a reboot to get back into it. All the while I've got a laptop a phone and a firestick all connected to the Pi-AP without any issue whatsoever.